# Is VIO a good solution for autonomous drone navigation at higher altiutues (200+ms)?

Tags: long-range-drone, autonomous

When it comes in indoor scenarios, VIOs may provide good performance, but when it comes to outdoor environments and high altitudes without proper GPS coverage/stability, are current VIOs capable of providing robust localization/navigation? are they used commercially at such height/environments?

I want to know if there are better solutions other than VIOs for autonomous navigation that are robust. I was looking at other approaches for autonomous navigation and found about depth-camera, laser range finders and optitrack? solutions as well, but it seems these solution only work at low altitudes.
So VIO seemed like the only option as you install a cheap monocular/stereo camera and you go on about your business.
However, it seems VIO algorithms are not robust enough and also there is dust/fog and even night that normal RGB cameras cant handle.
So if I want to build a robust navigation system what should I turn to? depth cameras? or RGB cameras and estimate the depth myself?
whats the current solution thats being used today?